# Moving/copying files off onedrive to external drive XP

Tags: windows-xp, onedrive, external-drive

Moving/copying files off onedrive to external drive XP

It only gives me options to move to folders within onedrive. Not to external destinations

I don't have win 8

Please help. I have 1200 photos I need to move

Comment: download them from server .. .

Comment: I don't really see the problem here. Do you have the [OneDrive client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=248256) installed (I don't know if it's available for Windows XP)? Then you can just copy and past as you normally would.

Comment: The client does not support XP.  It never did.

Comment: Okay I couldn't find that on the download page, I'll edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You have only 1 option using Windows XP:**

Download all photos from the OneDrive web client as a ZIP file and extract them to your external hard drive:

- Go to the [OneDrive web client](https://onedrive.com/)
- Log in with the account holding the photos
- Right click on the folder with the photos and choose `Download` (this will download the whole folder as a ZIP file)
- Wait for the download to complete, this can take some time depending on your connection speed and the size of the photos obviously
- Open the ZIP file (Windows XP has built-in support for these) and copy all photos to your external hard drive as you normally would

**Using Windows Vista or later you can also:**

Install the OneDrive client, wait for the sync to complete and then copy the files to your external hard drive:

- Download and install the [OneDrive client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=248256)
- Configure the OneDrive client with the account holding the photos
- Wait for the sync to completely finish (you can see the status in the system tray, this can take some time depending on your connection speed and the size of the photos obviously)
- Copy all photos from your OneDrive folder to your external hard drive as you normally would

Comment: Thank you so far it's downloading a huge file. 1200 videos & photos. However my new problem is the file keeps failing, it may be the antivirus software is picking up the file as it's taking so long? Any ideas on how I could stop this from happening. I'm using AVG FREE version. And all help very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll ask a friend with a MAC. This has been the most helpful forum I've found on IT.

Comment: Hello, it depends on the error, it's hard to say without more info. Using another pc is a good idea too of course!

Comment: Help still required: Mac has downloaded file and now it won't move it to ext drive. Tried moving any mac file to omega drive and it won't go. From omega drive to mac it works. ?

Comment: Hey, you best ask a new question for this for more attention! :)

Answer (score 1):

One Drive does not support Windows XP.  The only way to export files in XP is via the web interface (and even then support is spotty for older versions of Internet Explorer that XP supports and you may have to download them one at a time).  You will have to download them to your computer, and then copy them to your external drive.  Windows XP was never officially supported by SkyDrive/OneDrive, even when it first came out.

Frankly, your best option is to find another computer to use (Windows Vista/7/8/8.1 or a Mac)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tool named SyncDriver from here: http://syncdriver.com.
They still support Windows XP platform.